# MultipleObjectsReturned in complex queryset while result should be unique

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using Django 2.0 and running into strange issues with a queryset `needs` generated from a union() of two querysets:

```
needs.get(pk="3fbdcc49-2f06-46ea-a0a3-587ac5aaf50f")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MultipleObjectsReturned                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-300ad17a22c2> in <module>()
----> 1 needs.get(pk="3fbdcc49-2f06-46ea-a0a3-587ac5aaf50f")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    405         raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
    406             "get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!" % 
--> 407             (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
    408         )
    409
```

and with the same queryset:

```
for n in needs:
    print(n.pk)

3fbdcc49-2f06-46ea-a0a3-587ac5aaf50f
7c134214-6309-4881-b381-016cc00a31a5
```

So: `needs` is a queryset with two objects, one of it with its primary key (a UUID) set as `3fbdcc49-2f06-46ea-a0a3-587ac5aaf50f`. But the `get()` function raises MultipleObjectsReturned.

Any idea what causes such behaviour? Is it right to look for a UUID with its string representation?

Without bothering you too much with my models, here is how I generate the `needs`queryset:

```
own_needs = models.Need.objects.filter(owner="bfd8e679-7660-4dcd-83bd-614fbd99b506")
mandate=models.ListMandate.objects.get(mandated=user1, permission=models.ListMandate.CAN_BUY_NEEDS, revoked_on=None)
shared_needs=models.Need.objects.filter(list=mandate.target)
needs = own_needs.union(shared_needs)
```

Thanks for your enlightenment!

Comment: Note that using `needs = (own_needs | shared_needs).distinct()` works as expected. I suspect that Django's `union()` is still a bit fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Union may result in duplicates.Try to use `distinct` with result `queryset`.

```
needs = own_needs.union(shared_needs).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did use `distinct()`, no change. As you see, there are no duplicates in the queryset/DB anyway.
[Django documentation specifically says that union() returns distinct results.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#union)